# Orbits of binary pulsars. How to calculate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

If I may ask: How can the orbits of binary pulsar stars, with similar mass, be calculated from Kepler's laws? Considering that both large central masses must be located at their mutual foci. Also, how can the period be in proportion to each semi-major axis? Can one closed implicate calculation be used, or is it only arrived at recursively (excluding computer algorithms).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a star system fit to conic equation](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169374/)

Comment: I believe you can find the answer to your question in the answer I gave to http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/169393/26969 - the short answer is that it follows the _vis viva_ equation but with the sum of the masses of the two objects where normally the mass of the heavier one goes.

Comment: So pleased to have an answer. I suspected the center of masses might be at the focus. however, I was lost from there. Very good, floris!